# Spring SecurityによるCSRF対策の実現方法

Tags: java, spring

Spring SecurityでCSRF対策機能だけ使うには、どのような記述をxmlファイルに追加すればいいのでしょうか？

現在、Spring MVC 4.3.2を用いてWebアプリケーションを作成しています。ユーザー登録・ログイン・ログアウト機能などを、自前で実装し終わったところで、ユーザー登録・ログインフォームにCSRF対策を施したいと考えました。これも自前で実装しても良いのですが、Spring SecurityにCSRF対策を自動で行ってくれる機能があるようなので、それを使うことにしました。Spring Securityの最新版をMavenの依存性に追加し、Web上の情報にしたがって以下の設定をSpringのxmlファイルに追記しました。

```
<security:http auto-config="true"/>
```

この状態でアプリケーションを起動したところ、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
    No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined:
    Did you forget to add a global <authentication-manager> element to your configuration (with child <authentication-provider> elements)?
    Alternatively you can use the authentication-manager-ref attribute on your <http> and <global-method-security> elements.
```

そこで、xmlファイルの追加記述を以下のように変更しました。

```
<security:http auto-config="true"/>
<security:authentication-manager/>
```

この変更でエラーは出ないようになったのですが、CSRFトークンがHTMLに挿入されておらず、困っています。ちなみに、web.xmlの方にはDelegatingFilterProxyを追加済みです。

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: CSRFトークンを出したいHTMLないしはJSPのコードも合わせて書くと回答が得られると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

まず、web.xmlに書く`DelegatingFilterProxy`ですが、質問文に記載してあるものは私が`spring-session`を使うために設定したものでした。てっきり`filter-class`が同じなので追加する必要はないと思っていたのですが、`filter-name`によって識別されるようで、Spring Security用に`springSecurityFilterChain`という`filter-name`でfilterを作成する必要があるようです。

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

この状態で、Spring Security自体は動くようになったと言えます。しかしながら、bean定義のxmlのほうがこれだとまだ不十分で、今のままだと、どのページにアクセスしようとしてもログインを促されてしまいます（表示されるページはSpring Securityによって用意されたものと思われます）。そこで、`http`要素を以下のように書き換えます。

```
<security:http>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="login"/>
</security:http>
```

ここで、`login-page`はログインするページのURL、`login-processing-url`はログインフォームのsubmit先です。

最後に、[公式ドキュメント](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html)には

> If you are using Spring MVC  tag or Thymeleaf 2.1+ and are using @EnableWebSecurity, the CsrfToken is automatically included for you (using the CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor).

と書いてありますが、自動で`input`タグが作られるわけではなく、自分でCSRFトークンを入れる`input`タグを作ってやらなければならないようです（使用していたのはThymeleaf 2.1.5）。

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```